Не могу подключиить свой компонент к тоасту vue3-toastify
import { toast } from 'vue3-toastify';
import 'vue3-toastify/dist/index.css';


const notify = () => {
  toast(<BaseAlert message="Message" />);
}

Такой вариант работает:

const notify = () => {
  toast(BaseAlert);
}

Но мне нужен компонент с пропсом
https://vue3-toastify.js-bridge.com/usage/render-more-than-string.html
